# iOS Swift - Text to Speech make the app crash

Tags: ios, swift, crash, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I have an app with Text To Speech feature when clicking on a button. My code worked fine until it made the app crash. I think this bug must be related to the new release of iOS 9.3.3 but I can't find anything on the net that's why I'm posting here.

Here is the function triggered by a button:

```
func textToSpeech(){

  let textSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

  let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: self.targetLanguage)

  utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: self.languageFlag)

  textSynthesizer.speakUtterance(utterance)

}
```

When I click on the button I get this error on the AVSpeechSynthesizer initialisation :

[image: Error : Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code:1, address: 0x0)]

And in console: 
(lldb)

Does anyone has an idea of how to fix this ?
Thanks, 
Alex

Comment: If you added `print`s for `self.targetLanguage` and `self.languageFlag` what would they say...?

Comment: Yes I already checked, I get the value of each string which is not empty (The code was working fine when I wrote it a few months ago). self.targetLanguage is the word translated in the language I target and self.languageFlag is the locale of the language (which is supported by TTS).

Comment: Did you ever figure out a fix for this? I'm seeing the same thing on iOS 10. It doesn't happen every time, but it happens fairly often. I've been using AVSpeechSynthesizer heavily since iOS 7, and haven't made any changes to my speech code recently.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -:

```
    func text2Speech(text: String,languageCode: String) {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback,mode: .default)
        
    } catch let error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    let speechUtterance: AVSpeechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
    speechUtterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate / 2.0
    speechUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: languageCode)
    
    speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
}
```